# UIView layer shadow darkens after rotation

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIView that I'm using as a header, and I've applied a drop shadow to this view. It gets onscreen as I intended, but after a rotation the shadow becomes twice as dark, as though it had been redrawn over top of itself. Subsequent rotations make it even darker. Here is the code for the header and shadow:

```
self.header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, HEADER_HEIGHT)];
self.header.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.header.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

// Drop shadow.
self.header.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.header.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
self.header.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0;
self.header.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 2);
//        self.header.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
//        self.header.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
```

This code all occurs in viewWillLayoutSubviews of my View Controller, and call [super willLayoutSubviews] at the beginning of the method. I have tried putting the same code in viewWillAppear:animated to no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While writing this question out, I figured out the solution.
I was re-initializing the header every time viewWillLayout subviews was called.
Aside from being inefficient, this also caused the shadow to draw over itself for some reason.
I fixed this by initializing all of my views in loadView, and doing the frame setting in viewWillLayoutSubviews. This resolved the issue, and is nicer because I am not re-initializing objects that already exist.